# Объясните пожалуйста как работать со связями 1-ко-многим в Entity Framework на уровне сервисов

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, crud

Вот предположим у нас есть следующие сущности

```
  public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}
    public string Patronimic {get; set;}
    public virtual Company Company {get; set;}
    public Company()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
  public class Company 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string Lastname {get; set;}
    public string Patronimic {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
    public Company()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
}
```

Как я могу построить запрос на добавление Employee при условии что внешний ключ Company не может быть NULL. То-есть ключ должен присваиваться прямо в методе CreateEmployee

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте организовать Модели (или Сущности) по другому.

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName {get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string Lastname {get; set;}
        public string Patronimic {get; set;}
        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; } 

        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public virtual Company Company {get; set;}
        
    }

      public class Company 
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName {get; set;}
    }
```

Далее, вам нужно создавать CRUD-операции для этих двух моделей. Для извлечения выпадающего списка существующих компаний,  можно использовать ViewBag, но лучше придерживаться принципа строгой типизации Представлений, так что для Работников нужно еще будет создавать ViewModel.  Вот [здесь](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky) репозиторий с рабочим кодом ASP.NET Core MVC для .NET 5, в котором аналогичная проблема решается для связей Товаров и их Категорий.

Comment: Я вместо DataAnnotations использую Fluent API

Comment: А ещё забыл уточнить что создаю Web API